# Custom ListView doesn't display entries

Tags: android, listview

I've created a custom ListView with a BaseAdapter. When I start the activity, I see an empty ListView with no entries.

Here's the `Adapter` class:

```
public class SpeiseplanListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<SpeiseplanEntry> data;
private Context context;


public SpeiseplanListAdapter(ArrayList<SpeiseplanEntry> data, Context context) {
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View entry = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_entry, parent, false);

    TextView day = (TextView) entry.findViewById(R.id.text_day);
    TextView date = (TextView) entry.findViewById(R.id.text_date);
    TextView firstDish = (TextView) entry.findViewById(R.id.text_first_dish);
    TextView secondDish = (TextView) entry.findViewById(R.id.text_second_dish);

    SpeiseplanEntry current = data.get(position);

    day.setText(current.getDay());
    date.setText(current.getDate());
    firstDish.setText(current.getFirstDish());
    secondDish.setText(current.getSecondDish());

    return entry;
}
}
```

The `OnCreate()` method :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_speiseplan);
    SpeiseplanListAdapter adapter = new SpeiseplanListAdapter(entries, getApplicationContext());
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    ...

}
```

The Layout of a single row:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                         android:orientation="vertical"
                                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                         android:layout_height="120dp">

<TextView
        android:text="MO"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp" android:id="@+id/text_day" android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:typeface="monospace" android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp" android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="28dp"/>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:id="@+id/text_first_dish"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/text_day" android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:text="firstDish"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"/>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:id="@+id/text_second_dish"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/text_day" android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" android:text="secondDish"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"/>
<TextView
        android:text="21.09."
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/text_date"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp" app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" android:textSize="18sp"
        android:fontFamily="monospace" android:typeface="monospace" android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>
```

The layout of the `Activity`:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="de.gymoth.goapp.SpeiseplanActivity" tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">
<ListView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/list_speiseplan"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" android:divider="@color/divider" android:dividerHeight="1dp"/>
```

Is there a problem with the `ConstraintLayout` I used for the single row? Or is the `Adapter` the problem? **Any help is appreciated.**

Comment: Silly question, but does your `entries` variable contain a list with values in it?

Comment: Yes, the ArrayList is OK, I've checked that. Sorry, I forget to write that :)

Comment: To check adapter is working on not, place your breakpoint into getView method. If that hit then your Adapter is fine

Comment: Where do you initialize the entries list? I don't see it in your code sample. If it occurs after you are applying the adapter to the listview, it will not update in the adapter. If you update the list, you will have to call  `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter.

Comment: There must be an issue with your Arraylist/enteries. I tried your code and its working fine at my end

Comment: I initialize the ArrayList before setting the Adapter. I've checked that the ArrayList is filled using Log.i. Here's the whole onCreate() function: [link](https://hastebin.com/olomikofej.vbs)

Comment: @ Tacoboy >> please have a look at Vivek Modi's solution. I think he is on the right track but instead of `View entry = ` it should be `convertView = `

Comment: I've just found the problem - I used the Jsoup library to parse HTML from a website to java strings. I set a wrong if-condition, so the ArrayList was empty. Thanks to Vivek Modi and Barns52 for their suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first put a condition at inflate time...

```
if(convertView==null){
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View entry = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_entry, parent, false);
}
```

then use of holder in adapter..

Comment: @ Vivek Modi >> I think you are on the right track, but I think `entry` should actually be `convertView`. Like this: `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_entry, parent, false);`

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...

ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_speiseplan);
SpeiseplanListAdapter adapter = new SpeiseplanListAdapter(entries, YourActivityName.this);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

...
}
```